# operation history from Scanner

Tags: java, arrays, input

Hello everyone i'm doing my homework and i want to understand, how to fulfill properly third section in code - 3.View operation history. (List of all operations performed by user, use array for storing this information in format: “[operation index]. [operation name] - [user input]”. Also i have an issue - 
    Application should work and accept user input  until he wants  to exit from program.

```
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please select operation");
        System.out.println("1.Encode");
        System.out.println("2.Decode");
        System.out.println("3.View operation history");
        System.out.println("4.Exit program");

        Integer userInput = Integer.valueOf(in.nextLine());
        if (userInput.equals(1)) {
            System.out.println("You chosen encoding operation");
            System.out.println("Please choose codec name  - caesar or morse");

            String userInputEncode = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            if (userInputEncode.equals("caesar")) {
                System.out.println("Enter text to encode");
                String userInputEncode2 = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();
                System.out.println("Encoded text: " + caesarEncoder.encode(userInputEncode2));
            } else if (userInputEncode.equals("morse")) {
                System.out.println("Enter text to encode");
                String userInputEncode3 = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();
                System.out.println("Encoded text: " + morseEncoder.encode(userInputEncode3));

            } else
                System.out.println("You entered wrong codec name, try one more time");


        } else if (userInput.equals(2)) {
            System.out.println("You chosen decoding operation");
            System.out.println("Please choose codec name  - caesar or morse");
            String userInputDecode = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            if (userInputDecode.equals("caesar")) {
                System.out.println("Enter text to decode");
                String userInputDecode2 = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();
                System.out.println("Decoded text: " + caesarDecoder.decode(userInputDecode2));

            } else if (userInputDecode.equals("morse")) {
                System.out.println("Enter text to Decode");
                String userInputDecode3 = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();
                System.out.println("Decoded text: " + morseDecoder.decode(userInputDecode3));
            }
            else
                System.out.println("You entered wrong codec name, try one more time");

        }
        else if (userInput.equals(3)) {

        }
        else if (userInput.equals(4)) {
            in.close();
            System.out.println("Program was closed by user");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need a loop that checks if the user has typed the number 4.

Then you can create a List before the loop where you will store all the history of what the user has typed during the execution of the program.

And then in the case of the number 3 is selected, you can use that list to take the historical data and then print all the data that you need

Below a simple and fast example (not the best way):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
List<String> operationHistory=new ArrayList<String>();
Integer userInput = null;
do{
    System.out.println("Please select operation");
    System.out.println("1. aaa");
    System.out.println("2. bbb");
    System.out.println("3. print selection history");
    System.out.println("4. exit");
    userInput = Integer.valueOf(in.nextLine());

    if (userInput.equals(1)) {
        System.out.println("Please type something");
        String userInputEncode = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        operationHistory.add("1. aaa - " + userInputEncode);
    }else if (userInput.equals(2)) {.
        System.out.println("Please type something");
        String userInputEncode = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        operationHistory.add("2. bbb - " + userInputEncode);
    }else if (userInput.equals(3)) {
        System.out.println("Operation History:");
        for(String operationitem:operationHistory){
            System.out.println(operationitem);
        }
        System.out.println("-------------");
    }

}while(!userInput.equals(4));
in.close();
System.out.println("Program was closed by user");
```

This is just an example similar to your code, you can use it to understand how your problem can be solved and how the loops and the lists works

You then probably want to manage some unexpected input

Comment: @Daeris If this have solved your problem you can accept the answer, If you have some problem with it don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: @Daeris by the way, your question was downvoted probably for the fact that the title it's not quite right(the Scanner class doesn't have the history) and the fact that as it's really specific to your homework it will unlikely be helpful for other person, would be awesome if you can edit the question in a more generic way like "how to use a loop with a condition based on the input of the user" and "how to keep track of the user input in a loop" so it will be less specific to the homework and more specific to the actual problem